# Checking if there is some square root of an element over an extension of the field of 5-adic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory, splitting-field

Let us consider the splitting field $L$ of $f = x^3 - 135x - 270$ over $\mathbb{Q}_5$, and let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3 \in L$. Let $\beta = (\alpha_2 - \alpha_1)^3$.

> **Question**: How do I check if $L$ contains a square root of $\beta$?

I tried to approach this problem by noting that
$
L = \{ c_0 + c_1 \alpha + c_2 \alpha_2^2 \: | \: c_i \in \mathbb{Q}_5 \}
$
for any $\alpha = \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$.

For $\gamma = c_0 + c_1 \alpha + c_2 \alpha_2^2$ we have

$$ \begin{align} \gamma^2 &= c_0^2 + 2 c_0 c_1 \alpha + (2 c_0 c_2 + c_1^2) \alpha^2 + 2 c_1 c_2 \alpha^3 + c_2^2 \alpha^4 \\ 
& = c_0^2 + 2c_0 c_1 \alpha + (2 c_0 c_2 + c_1^2) \alpha^2 + 2 c_1 c_2 (135 \alpha + 270) + c_2^2 (135 \alpha^2 + 270 \alpha) \\
&= c_0^2 + 540 c_1 c_2 + (2 c_0 c_1 + 270 c_1 c_2 + 270 c_2^2) \alpha + (2 c_0 c_2 + c_1^2 + 135 c_2^2) \alpha^2. \end{align} $$

Also, we have 
$$
\begin{align} 
\beta = (\alpha_2 - \alpha_1)^2 &= \alpha_2^3 - 3 \alpha_1 \alpha_2^2  + 3 \alpha_1^2 \alpha_2 - \alpha_1^3 \\
&= -135 \alpha_1 + 135 \alpha_2 + 3 \alpha_1^2 \alpha_2 - 3 \alpha_1 \alpha_2^2
\end{align}
$$

Since I want to have $\gamma^2 = \beta$, I could compare the coefficients of both terms for choosing $\alpha$ as $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ or $\alpha_3$. But this approach does not seem to be very promising since I would receive an armada of equations over $\mathbb{Q}_5$ with quadratic variables.

Is there any other approach for this problem? Maybe with valuations or something similar?

Comment: In general given a finite extension $K/Q_p$ you need to find $O_K = Z_p[\zeta_{p^f-1},\pi_K]$ (ie. uniformizer and residue field), then to check if a monic polynomial $h\in O_K[x]$ has a root you need to find $m$ such that $h\bmod p^m$ is separable, then $h$ has a root in $O_K$ iff it has a root in $O_K/(p^{(\deg(h)m)!})$ (extended Hensel lemma, where I never recall the optimal constant, it is much smaller than $(\deg(h)m)!$). For a square root and $p$ odd it is easier : for $a\in K$ then $a^{1/2}\in K$ iff $v(a)=2j v(\pi_K)$ and $a/\pi_K^{2j}\bmod (\pi_K)$ is a square.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence: What is $j$ supposed to be?

Comment: $2j$ is the valuation of $a$ when the valuation of $\pi_K$ is set to 1

Comment: Okay, so I can try to approach this problem by determining the valuation for $a = \beta$ according to your result. It is $v(\beta) = 3 v(\alpha_2 - \alpha_1)$. All I know is that this is less than $1$ since $v(\alpha_1) = v(\alpha_2) = 1/3$ (which can be computed by using Newton polygons). Is it possible to continue here?

Comment: In that case, it would be $2j < 1$. Is it even well-defined to look at $a/\pi_K^{2j}$ then? Because we do not know if $\pi_K^{2j}$ exists in $K$.